# Translation animation on button having issue, not responding as per expected

Tags: android, translate-animation

I am a newbie in Android. I am trying translate animation on buttons. i have added one button in xml, when clicked, another button which is programmatically added moves from its current position to the top of the screen and gets fixed. but the issue is that instead of starting from its current position it is starting from the position somewhere below and not getting fixed at the top. please someone help me if they can. Thanks in advance. 
Here is my code which i am using :-

```
    ll= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    final int width = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    final int height= this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;


   final Button btn=new Button(MainActivity.this);
   btn.setText("Message");
   btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   btn.setX(width/3);
   btn.setY(height/3);
   ll.addView(btn);

   Button btn_click= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonbottom);
   btn_click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     Animation animate= new TranslateAnimation(btn.getX(),btn.getX(), btn.getY(), 0);
     animate.setDuration(7000);
     btn.startAnimation(animate);
    }
});
}
```

and its xml is :-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonbottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Me" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create an xml file in your `/res/anim` folder and use it to animate your button. The `<translate>` tag with `android:fromYDelta` and `android:toYDelta` as its attributes may prove to be helpful (both the attributes are concerned with vertical movement of your button), and much easier here since your problem belongs to the category of translate animation problems. If you want to consider the same, you may find some good explanation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html).